# Selenium driver management in Springboot

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, spring-boot-test

I am trying to create a selenium framework using spring boot. What I am trying to accomplish it spring-boot should manage selenium driver creation, even when we run the test in parallel and if possible I want to avoid passing driver object in page class constructor.
So I created a bean class like below

```
@Bean
public WebDriver getDriver(){
            return new ChromeDriver();
}
```

it worked fine for the Single test. But for multiple tests in parallel, I changed the scope of the above method to the prototype, and when I ran the test it started multiple tests but it didn't work as I expected and commands started firing in the wrong browser. I know I am missing something related to Thread/parallel stuff. It would be really helpful if someone can guide me or someone can share git repo where spring-boot and selenium are used.

Answer (score 1):

You could try changing the scope to thread with:

```
@Bean
@Scope(value = "thread", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public WebDriver getDriver(){
            return new ChromeDriver();
}

@Bean
public static CustomScopeConfigurer customScopeConfigurer()
{
    CustomScopeConfigurer scopeConfigurer = new CustomScopeConfigurer();
    Map<String, Object> scopes = new HashMap<>();
    scopes.put("thread", SimpleThreadScope.class);
    scopeConfigurer.setScopes(scopes);
    return scopeConfigurer;
}
```

Comment: Can you throw some light on how you want to quit driver? As custom scope doesnt support destroyMethod was wondering how to achieve it!